# My supervisor at seasonal job is not returning my calls: Should I contact the company?

Tags: management

I just had an interview late last week for a seasonal job and I got hired on the spot, I was even asked to start training that day but I didn't have my social security card for my I-9 papers ( my parents lost it years ago) and my new supervisor and I agreed I would call her Monday after I went to the social security office. So I contacted the s.s office on Monday and they told me because I didn't have an actual state i.d. card ( that has also needed to be replaced recently and of course they give you a paper until you get your physical copy in the mail) I couldn't get my s.s. card. I called and left a message on the supervisor phone's about what I was told and asked her if I could submit my birth certificate instead for my I-9 and I have yet to hear back from her.

My question is,do I continue to try and reach her? I have the option of e-mailing the company (this job is at a Santa set in the mall) and reaching someone else about my papers but I really don't want to potentially aggravate a person I have to work with. What should I do? I need a job!

Comment: FIrst, let this be a lesson to you, that you need to have the things you need to have to get hired. It is not your parents' responsibility to get this stuff, it is yours.  Frankly you should not have applied for a job without a Social Security Card.

Comment: I'm well aware it is not my parents responsibility to get this stuff, I merely mentioned they lost the original card. I also am aware that though I do need to get s.s. card (though I know the number by heart), it is only one form of legal proof for my job records. Some jobs may prefer social security cards but they can also accept other proof.http://jobsearch.about.com/cs/backgroundcheck/a/background_2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the I9 form itself: http://www.uscis.gov/files/form/i-9.pdf  It answers your question for you, which is that a certified official copy of your birth certificate, along with a document from List B (see the form, last page) is fine, and legally MUST be accepted.  From the form:

> Employers cannot specify which document(s) employees may present from
>   the Lists of Acceptable Documents

As for contacting the company, I would try to contact the supervisor again.  It's possible that the person was not in and not heard your message yet or that they are busy and perhaps have forgotten to get back to you.

Ideally you'll have found the required documentation for the I9 and your message will be that you have the necessary information to complete it, let me know when you want me to come in.  Alternatively you can stop by in person.

However if they don't get back to you after that, I would probably say you need to continue your job search as they may have found someone else that did have their stuff together.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, my question is do I keep trying to contact the person the person I interviewed with or do I contact the company she works for and talk to them?

Comment: UPDATE: I just called and got a hold of the supervisor. Her claim is that the social security number proof is not for the I-9 but for basically some kind of other proof of my identity and that a birth certificate won't be accepted. I don't understand, is this legal?

Comment: @LisW Ive never personally had someone require that they see my SSN card (as long as I had other I9 acceptable documents instead) although for payroll tax reasons you must provide the number on other forms such as W4 at least.  I'd open another question on if what you were told is normal/reasonable to do so, but not legal as legal questions are off topic here.  Direct legal questions to your attorney.